# java.lang.ClassCastException: org.json.simple.JSONArray cannot be cast to org.json.JSONArray

Tags: java, android, json, classcastexception, filereader

I need to read a `JsonArray` data from a file (on an SD card) and store it into a SQLite database.

but I am getting a `java.lang.ClassCastException: org.json.simple.JSONArray cannot be cast to org.json.JSONArray` exception while parsing data to `JsonArray`.

Data in the file is very huge, the whole data can not be stored in a single String or String Buffer or String Builder.

Here is my code.

```
FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(file_path);
Object obj = jsonParser.parse(fileReader);
JSONArray jsonArray = (JSONArray) obj; // Exception.
```

Please help..

Comment: What libraries are you using beside standard Android?

Comment: I am using json-lib-2.2.2-jdk15.jar and json-simple-1.1.1.jar.

Comment: Shouldn't you try to use only one of them?

Comment: if I remove json-simple-1.1.1.jar, jsonParser throwing me an error.

Answer (score 8):

Check your import statements at the top of your source file.

You probably have a line saying:

```
import org.json.JSONArray;
```

It should instead be:

```
import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
```

If you are working in eclipse, or any other intelligent IDE, the problem probably happened when you started typing the line starting with `JSONArray`. At that point, the IDE would show you different possibilities of importing the class `JSONArray`. You have one in `org.json.JSONArray` and one in `org.json.simple.JSONArray`. The latter is the right one, but you choose the first one and your IDE automatically added an import line at the top of your source java file.

From the exception the problem is quite apparent, the exception tells you that your `obj` object cannot be cast to a `org.json.JSONArray` object as it is really a `org.json.simple.JSONArray` object. (Note that there is a different between the two).

**Update**

If you want to use `org.json.JSONArray` instead, you should use another class than `jsonParser` as this one is from the `org.json.simple` package. Currently you are mixing the two libraries, and that is what causes your troubles.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. but does org.json.JSONArray has jsonParser functionlity.? If I remove org.json.simple.JSONArray, jsonParser showing me an error..

Comment: @user2085965: If you don't want to do the parsing manually, you can use GSON and make life easier.

Comment: @user2085965: See my updated answer. You should remove `import org.json.JSONArray;` not `import org.json.simple.JSONArray;`

Comment: Very helpful - thanks!  In my case Eclipse entered "com.amazonaws.util.json.JSONArray" instead of "org.json.simple.JSONArray"

Answer (score 0):

You can first read the whole content of file into a String.

```
FileInputStream fileInputStream = null;
String data="";
StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer("");
try{
    fileInputStream=new FileInputStream(filename);
    int i;
    while((i=fileInputStream.read())!=-1)
    {
        stringBuffer.append((char)i);
    }
    data = stringBuffer.toString();
    csvFile.delete();
}
catch(Exception e){
        LoggerUtil.printStackTrace(e);
}
finally{
    if(fileInputStream!=null){  
        fileInputStream.close();
    }
}
```

Now You will have the whole content into String ( data variable ).

```
JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
org.json.simple.JSONArray jsonArray= (org.json.simple.JSONArray) parser.parse(data);
```

After that you can use jsonArray as you want.

Comment: Getting "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: org.json.simple.JSONObject cannot be cast to org.json.simple.JSONArray"