# Exception Converting Object to JSONObject

Tags: java, android, json

I am trying to convert an Object

```
Object jObj;
parser.parse(response);
jObj = parser.parse(response);
```

where response is

```
{"as":false,"autoToggleOff":false,"autoToggleSeconds":0,"cs":false,"deviceId":"e4e4217f-eef2-4cd8-9a87-21264ddff836","deviceName":"Virtual Switch One","deviceType":1,"displayOrder":0,"et":null,"he":false,"il":false,"isControllerBacked":true,"lastLevelUpdate":"\/Date(1413470244538-0400)\/","level":99,"levelPresets":[],"name":"Virtual Switch One","newLevel":null,"newPowerState":null,"newPowerTimerSeconds":null,"nextEventPowerLevel":null,"nextEventPowerOn":null,"nextEventTime":null,"nodeId":0,"pd":true,"providerDeviceId":"141009173344","pushUpdates":false,"roomId":null,"shortId":2,"sr":null,"st":null,"visible":true}
```

to a JSONObject from the Object

```
JSONObject jsonObject;
jsonObject = (JSONObject) jObj;
```

I get

```
10-16 11:09:04.962: W/dalvikvm(14259): threadid=12: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41d21d40)
```

The code is surrounded with a try / catch

```
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();    
} catch (ParseException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Is there an Exception I should be trying to catch? The code was working fine a few hours ago so I'm really stumped as to what has changed...

Thanks!

Comment: Don't the logs show the uncaught exception?

Comment: just "thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41d21d40)"

Comment: "thread exiting with uncaught exception" must have several causes, post all your LogCat messages or post your code.

Comment: We need more contextual code

Comment: I don't know how I missed this: "10-16 11:21:29.210: E/AndroidRuntime(14731): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.json.simple.JSONObject cannot be cast to org.json.JSONObject
" I'll look into that...

Comment: You're using the wrong `JSONObject` class. Import the right one.

Comment: Solved using http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20652284/java-lang-classcastexception-org-json-simple-jsonarray-cannot-be-cast-to-org-js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> java.lang.ClassCastException: org.json.simple.JSONObject cannot be
>   cast to org.json.JSONObject " I'll look into that...

seems like your imports are wrong. parser.parse seems to return another kind of jsonobject

Comment: Yup! was using "import org.json.JSONObject;" instead of "import org.json.simple.JSONObject;"

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was using

```
import org.json.JSONObject;
```

instead of

```
import org.json.simple.JSONObject
```