# Why am I now getting a cannot resolve method length error after using a fix according to a stackoverflow post(embedded)?

Tags: java, android

I am working on a project for a while and got stuck with getting a strange Cannot Cast Exception. I found the asnwer here on this post [java.lang.ClassCastException: org.json.simple.JSONArray cannot be cast to org.json.JSONArray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20652284/java-lang-classcastexception-org-json-simple-jsonarray-cannot-be-cast-to-org-js)
but when I did what it was suggesting and change my import statement I now have two new errors that pop up.

They are Error:(90, 39) error: cannot find symbol method getJSONObject(int)
Error:(89, 29) error: cannot find symbol method length()

Here is my code for MainActivity

```
import android.R;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.squareup.okhttp.Call;
import com.squareup.okhttp.Callback;
import com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient;
import com.squareup.okhttp.Request;
import com.squareup.okhttp.Response;
import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import butterknife.ButterKnife;


public class MainActivity extends Activity implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks {
    public static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private RadioData mRadioData;

    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private Location mLastLocation;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.list_content);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);

        Location locationUserLatitude = mLastLocation;
        Location locationUserLongitude = mLastLocation;
        Location latitudeStation;
        Location longitudeStation;
        RadioData mRadioData = new RadioData();

        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        String radioFinderURL = "http://dredaycreative.com/json/radioData.json";
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(radioFinderURL)
                .build();
        Call call = client.newCall(request);
        call.enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Request request, IOException e) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Response response) throws IOException {
                try {
                    String jsonData = response.body().string();
                    Log.v(TAG, jsonData);
                    if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                        getCurrentRadioData();
                    }

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Exception Caught: ", e);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Exception Caught:", e);
                }
            }

        });


    }


    private List getCurrentRadioData() throws JSONException{
        List radioData = new ArrayList<String>();
        List localRadioData = new ArrayList();
        Object obj=JSONValue.parse(String.valueOf(radioData));
        JSONArray data;
        data = (JSONArray)obj;
        float[] results = new float[3];
        double latitudeStation = 0;
        double longitudeStation = 0;
        for (int i=0; i<data.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject jasonObj = data.getJSONObject(i);
            double latitudeStations = jasonObj.getDouble("FIELD21");
            radioData.add(latitudeStations);
            double longitudeStations = jasonObj.getDouble("FIELD24");
            radioData.add(longitudeStations);
            Location.distanceBetween(mLastLocation.getLatitude(), mLastLocation.getLongitude(), latitudeStation, longitudeStation, results);
            float distance = results[0];
            distance = Math.round(distance);

            if ((distance) > 350) {
                JSONObject callsign = jasonObj.getJSONObject("FIELD1");
                localRadioData.add(callsign);
                JSONObject frequency = jasonObj.getJSONObject("FIELD2");
                localRadioData.add(frequency);
            } else {
            radioData.add(getCurrentRadioData());

            }


        }

        return localRadioData;
    }



    private void updateDisplay() {

    }


    protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener((GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener) this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();


    }


    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(
                mGoogleApiClient);
        if (mLastLocation != null) {
          //  mLatitudeLabel.setText(String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLatitude()+ ""));
           // mLongitudeLabel.setText(String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLongitude()+""));
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }


}
```

my RadioData.java

```
  /**
     * Created by Andreas on 8/10/2015.
     */
    public class RadioData {
    public String getCallSign() {
        return mCallsign;
    }

    public void setCallSign(String callsign) {
        mCallsign = callsign;
    }

    public double getFrequency() {
        return mFrequency;
    }

    public void setFrequency(double frequency) {
        mFrequency = frequency;
    }

    public int getChannel() {
        return mChannel;
    }

    public void setChannel(int channel) {
        mChannel = channel;
    }

    public double getLatitude() {
        return mLatitude;
    }

    public void setLatitude(double latitude) {
        mLatitude = latitude;
    }

    public double getLongitude() {
        return mLongitude;
    }

    public void setLongitude(double longitude) {
        mLongitude = longitude;
    }

    private String mCallsign;
    private double mFrequency;
    private int mChannel;
    private double mLatitude;
    private double mLongitude;



}
```

activity main xml

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                tools:context=".MainActivity"
                android:background="#ffffed">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

jsonParse

```
package com.dredaydesigns.radiostationfinder;

/*
 * $Id: JSONValue.java,v 1.1 2006/04/15 14:37:04 platform Exp $
 * Created on 2006-4-15
 */

import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;

import java.io.Reader;
import java.io.StringReader;


/**
 * @author FangYidong<fangyidong@yahoo.com.cn>
 */
public class JSONValue {
    /**
     * parse into java object from input source.
     * @param in
     * @return instance of : JSONObject,JSONArray,String,Boolean,Long,Double or null
     */
    public static Object parse(Reader in){
        try{
            JSONParser parser=new JSONParser();
            return parser.parse(in);
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            return null;
        }
    }

    public static Object parse(String s){
        StringReader in=new StringReader(s);
        return parse(in);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using 2 different JSON libraries that might create conflict on your code.

You are using `JSONArray` and `JSONValue` from the [JSON Simple](https://code.google.com/p/json-simple/) library and `JSONObject` and `JSONException` from [org.json](http://www.json.org/) library.

Try to use either one. I hope that will solve your issue.

**EDIT:**

You got the first error (before applying the fix) because you have used `JSONValue` class from [JSON Simple](https://code.google.com/p/json-simple/) to parse the data and `JSONArray` from [org.json](http://www.json.org/) to store it. That causes a class cast exception.

After applying the fix, You have used `JSONValue` and `JSONArray` classes from [JSON Simple](https://code.google.com/p/json-simple/) to parse and store the data in array form and `JSONObject` from [org.json](http://www.json.org/) to store objects on the `JSONArray`. In this case, the `org.json.simple.JSONArray` class doesn't have `getJSONObject(int)` and `length()` methods where as `org.json.JSONArray` have them. So you got those 2 exceptions.